# JavaFX on MacOS ARM: Graphics Device initialization failed

Tags: java, macos, intellij-idea, javafx, macos-big-sur

I am using JavaFX on a MacBook M1 inside the Intellij IDE. My application builds and runs as expected within Intellij, but when I build the application into an executable jar and run it from  the terminal I receive the error:

```
Graphics Device initialization failed for :  es2, sw
Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer.getInstance(QuantumRenderer.java:280)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumToolkit.init(QuantumToolkit.java:222)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:260)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Error initializing QuantumRenderer: no suitable pipeline found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.init(QuantumRenderer.java:94)
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.quantum.QuantumRenderer$PipelineRunnable.run(QuantumRenderer.java:124)
    ... 1 more
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: No toolkit found
    at com.sun.javafx.tk.Toolkit.getToolkit(Toolkit.java:272)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:267)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.startup(PlatformImpl.java:158)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.startToolkit(LauncherImpl.java:658)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.launchApplication1(LauncherImpl.java:678)
    at com.sun.javafx.application.LauncherImpl.lambda$launchApplication$2(LauncherImpl.java:195)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

I have found possible solutions about graphic driver issues, but the fact that the application ran just fine within the IDE makes me believe that wouldn't be the issue (also none of the solutions were for the M1 MacBooks). If any other information is needed please let me know! Thank you in advance!

Comment: How are you building the JAR file? What is the command you use to launch the JAR file?

Comment: **File** > **Project Structure** > **Artifacts**, click the  "+", **JAR** > **From modules with dependencies...**. I make my main class my main file associated with my application and then click **Apply** and **Okay**. Then I go to **Build** > **Build Artifacts** and select the one I just created and click **Build**. The command I run in my terminal is `java -jar Planner.java`

Comment: Are you using the JavaFX SDK (or a JDK with JavaFX included), or are you using the JavaFX JAR files from Maven Central?

Comment: I am using JavaFX SDK 11.02

Comment: The issue is the native code is not being included in your fat JAR file. You have a few options: (1) Don't build a fat JAR and simply point to JavaFX when executing your application from the command line; (2) Use the JavaFX JARs published to Maven Central since they embed the native code; (3) Package your application with `jlink` and `jpackage` (latter tool added in Java 14). For this option you'll want to use the JMOD files for JavaFX (can be downloaded from Gluon, same place you get the SDK).

Comment: Where did you get a JavaFX for M1 (ARM) from?

Answer (score 4):

Try [Liberica OpenJDK](https://bell-sw.com/pages/downloads/#/java-16-current) , works on MacBook Pro 2020 M1.
I had the same issue, after installing the full version which has LibericaFX, the issue resolved.

- **Full version** of Liberica includes LibericaFX, which is based on OpenJFX and Minimal VM, where suitable.
- **Standard version** is best suited for server and desktop deployments that do not require any additional components.
- **Lite version** of Liberica works best for cloud deployments and is optimized for size.

also available on `HomeBrew`

```sh
brew tap bell-sw/liberica
brew install liberica-jdk16-full
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as yours and the solution is to specify the right dependency classifier for `javafx-graphics`, i.e. `<classifier>mac-aarch64</classifier>`. Please have a look at my pom.xml. It is running on my Mac with Apple M1 silicon :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>my_group</groupId>
    <artifactId>my_app</artifactId>
    <version>1.0</version>
    <name>my_app</name>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <junit.version>5.8.2</junit.version>
        <javafx.version>20-ea+4</javafx.version>
        <java.version>18</java.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-controls</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-fxml</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>mac</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
            <artifactId>javafx-graphics</artifactId>
            <version>${javafx.version}</version>
            <classifier>mac-aarch64</classifier>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-api</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.junit.jupiter</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter-engine</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-shade-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.2.3</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>shade</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <transformers>
                                <transformer
                                        implementation="org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.resource.ManifestResourceTransformer">
                                    <mainClass>Launcher</mainClass>
                                </transformer>
                            </transformers>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.10.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>${java.version}</source>
                    <target>${java.version}</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.openjfx</groupId>
                <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>0.0.8</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <!-- Default configuration for running with: mvn clean javafx:run -->
                        <id>default-cli</id>
                        <configuration>
                            <mainClass>MyApp</mainClass>
                            <launcher>app</launcher>
                            <jlinkZipName>app</jlinkZipName>
                            <jlinkImageName>app</jlinkImageName>
                            <noManPages>true</noManPages>
                            <stripDebug>true</stripDebug>
                            <noHeaderFiles>true</noHeaderFiles>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```